# Can we Get same return type , if we select only one column or more than one column in hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I made One Class for executing hibernate select operations my code is
working fine  but i just need some help

I am passing hibernate select query from some other class to get the
result  if my select query contains more than one column than I call the
method getListbylimit(String query,int limit)  its returns
List but when my select query column contains only one than  it
gives exception   java.lang.String cannot be cast to
 `[Ljava.lang.Object;`

for that I made second method List
getListForSingleColumn(String query) to get the result for single
column

is there any way to write  method for this so that I can call only
one method. Rather my select query contain one column or more than one   columns.

can I get return type `List<Object[]>` if I select only one column instead of `List<String>` so that I can use only one method for select operation

Here is my code

```
public class ContentDomain {

    Session session;

    public List<Object[]> getListbylimit(String query,int limit){

        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
/*      session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
*/      
        List<Object[]> ls_ob = new ArrayList<Object[]>();

        Transaction tx = null;

        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();

        Query q = session.createQuery(query);
         q.setMaxResults(limit);
        ls_ob  = (List<Object[]>)q.list();

    }catch (HibernateException ex) {
        if (tx != null) {
            System.out.println("Exception in getList method " + ex);

              tx.rollback(); 
              ex.printStackTrace();

        }
        System.out.println("Exception getList tx open" + ex);
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }

        return ls_ob;
    }






public List<String> getListForSingleColumn(String query){

    session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    /*  session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();*/

        List<String> ls_ob = new ArrayList<String>();

        Transaction tx = null;

        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();

        Query q = session.createQuery(query);

        ls_ob  = q.list();

    }catch (HibernateException ex) {
        if (tx != null) {
            System.out.println("Exception in getList method " + ex);

              tx.rollback(); 
              ex.printStackTrace();

        }
        System.out.println("Exception getList tx open" + ex);
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }

        return ls_ob;
    }



}
```

Comment: Can you give us some examples of some of the HQL queries you are passing to getListbylimit(), for instance, one HQL query that works as intended and another that causes the ClassCastException?

Comment: This is for more than one column

List<Object[]> ls  = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
String sql_query = "select prv,pricetag from tbl_name where cat like '"+cat+"' order by rand()";
 ls = cd.getListbylimit(sql_query,limit);

And query  for one column given below:

 List<String> ls  = new ArrayList<String>();
 String sql_query = "select distinct(cat) from tbl_name  group by cat";
 ls = cd.getListForSingleColumn(sql_query);

Comment: cd is instanse of class 
ContentDomain cd =  new ContentDomain();
i have already posted the source  code of that class

Answer (score 0):

If you use native queries (session.createSQLQuery("yournnativequery)) you'll always get a List of Object[] with .list()... then it's easy to do a single private parsing method to handle both outputs.

Comment: you're wrong: i've got the same issue with a character varying single column, the list() return a list of String arrays, not a list of Object arrays... I'm working with hibernate 4.1.6 (with JPA bean : org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter)

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `ls_ob  = (List<Object[]>)q.list();` with:

```
List<Object> result = q.list();
if (!result.isEmpty() && !(result.get(0) instanceof Object[])) {
  ls_ob = result.stream().map(o -> new Object[] {o}).collect(Collectors.toList());
} else {
  ls_osb = (List) result;
}
```

Basically, transform the single column query results manually.